# How to get top most parent in self reference object

Tags: database, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

**UPDATE**
This is my comment from bellow that I have discused with @Slauma:

> Because I need to get all locations that are connected to passed root
>   category. As you can see if I pass 2 and some location have category
>   44 and 44 is child of 32 which is child of 2 I need to get this
>   location. LocationCategory is N:N table in database between Locations
>   and PlaceCategories. Not important but can give a better picture. I
>   have a map and markers on that map. I can click on Education(id:2)
>   link and I need to get all markers where root of location category is
>   '2' (like on foursquare.com map)

I have a self reference table in database.
So I created the following object:

```
public class PlaceCategory
    {
        public int PlaceCategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }

        public virtual PlaceCategory Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PlaceCategory> Children { get; set; }

        public string Icon { get; set; }
    }
```

Because Location object can have multiple categories I have LocationCategory object:

```
public class LocationCategory
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public int PlaceCategoryId { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
        public virtual PlaceCategory PlaceCategory { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Location object have:

```
public class Location
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<LocationCategory> LocationCategories { get; set; } 
    ...
```

In database in self reference table I have:

```
root: Education (id:2, parentId:null)
child1: School(id:32, parentId:2) 
child2: Elementary(id:42,parentId:32), High(id:43,parentId:32), Higher(id:44,parentId:32) etc.
```

I have to take list of locations based on passed root category.

```
var model = locationRepository.GetLocationss().Where(x => x.LocationCategories???); // but it's a list and don't know how to check top most parent here?
```

So if I pass '2' I should get all items which have category 2,32,42,43,44

Comment: "*list of locations based on passed root category*": Could you describe more precisely what you want to query? Also I don't see any self-reference. And what tables do `root`, `child1`, `child2` refer to?

Comment: I updated my whole question. I forgot to add self reference object. At the end of the question I added example of what I need to query.

Comment: Are the `Location` and `LocationCategory` entities relevant for your question at all? According to your last sentence you just want to load only `PlaceCategory` entities, basically a flattened list of the whole `PlaceCategory` graph starting from the given root, don't you? But why do you start with `locationRepository.GetLocationss()` then?

Comment: Because I need to get all locations that are connected to passed root category. As you can see if I pass 2 and some location have category 44 and 44 is child of 32 which is child of 2 I need to get this location. LocationCategory is N:N table in database between Locations and PlaceCategories. Not important but can give a better picture. I have a map and markers on that map. I can click on Education(id:2) link and I need to get all markers where root of location category is '2' (like on foursquare.com map)

Comment: Aaaah, now I understand! +1, interesting question :) I suggest to edit your last comment into the question because that's pretty important to understand the whole question. I don't think that you can find a single LINQ query to get this result (how to query through a tree of unknown depth with LINQ?). I have no idea what's the best way to perform such a query. You should also tag the question with DB and version because a possible solution might be a stored procedure.

Comment: My understanding is that the `Where` clause in your last code snippet would basically have to be like this: `Where(x => x.LocationCategories.Any(lc => lc.PlaceCategory.Parent.Parent.Parent....ParentId == 2))`, but the problem is that you can't say at compile time know how often to chain `.Parent`, so this approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by entity framework unless you add `rootCategoryId` to every `PlaceCategory` and filter on that property when retrieving locations but this approach will fail once you have deeper nesting and you may require to get all locations for some category which is not root (but have its own parent). In such case storing the root will not help.

The generalization of this problem is called hierarchical or recursive query. That is the query which can traverse hierarchy and get all required nested records. It is possible to do that with SQL by using [Common Table Expression alias CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (requires SQL Server 2005 or newer). You can create such query and execute it directly by `dbContext.Database.SqlQuery`.

In case of EF 5.0 with .NET 4.5 and EDMX (database first) you would be also able to implement the query as Table Valued Function in SQL Server, map it in EDMX and use it in Linq queries.